# How to prove this statement?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I cannot prove this proposition directly .

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ be metrice spaces. Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. If $\overline{f^{-1} ( B)} \subseteq f^{-1}( \overline B)$ for all subset $B$ of $Y$, then 
>   $f$ is sequentially continuous.

Note that $f$ is sequentially continuous if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)$, if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$, then $d′(f(x_n),f(x)) \to 0$.
 Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not, we have a subsequence of $f(x_n)$ s.t. $d'(f(x_{n_k}),f(x))\ge \epsilon$.WOLG, we assume the subsequence is $f(x_n)$ and $x_n\not =x\forall n$ (otherwise restrict our discussion to suitable subsequence).

Then set $B=\{f(x_n)\}$, hence $ \{(x_n)\}\subset f^{-1} ( B),\{(x_n)\}\cup \{x\}\subset \overline{f^{-1} ( B)}$ since $x_n\to x$

By assumption $\overline{f^{-1} ( B)} \subseteq f^{-1}( \overline B)$ , then $x\in
f^{-1}( \overline B)$, hence $f(x)\in \bar{B}$. which is impossible, by our selection of$f(x_n)$

Hence we get sequential continuity.

Comment: How does one ensure that a convergent subsequence of $f(x_n)$ exists? i thought that is only when the metric space is compact. Also will it only converge to some point in the image of $f$; can't it converge to any point outside? Thanks!

Comment: @Raisa You are right. I have made a mistake. Please see if it's clearer now.

Comment: Now it is perfect!

Comment: I have upvoted it but I think accepting can only be done by the person who asked the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, Raisa and John ZHAG.